# NSIS Installer Error Flag

Tags: nsis

In some of the NSIS Installer documentation, it says that if some operation fails, the error flag will be set. Is the error flag just a boolean value or is a specific code that indicates what error occurred? If it is a code, how do I access it to log it out?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is just a boolean flag, use `ClearErrors`, `IfErrors` and `SetErrors` to clear/detect/set it. (This flag is set by the internal instructions, most plugins use other methods but it is also possible for a plugin to set/clear it)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to actually figure out what went wrong? I'm getting an empty value reading an existent registry key.

Comment: @JeffStorey: Not really, you can try the NSIS logging build ( http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Special_Builds ) but for file/registry issues like this I usually recommend trying Process Monitor first...